# Cannot create new project with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I tried to start new project with VS2022 and after creating it first time I noticed misspell so I deleted whole solution and tried to create new one again and now I am getting this error "This directory name is invalid" and the deleted folder keep recreating

[Visual studio error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZPVr.png)

Comment: What was the page BEFORE the error?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I selected Standalone Typescript Angular Project and then filled out Project name and Solution name. Project location path is default one and I already have few project there from before.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like pending fix to be released soon...

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/standalone-typescript-angular-directory-is-invalid/1668068

Comment: Thanks, I found a workaround until issue is fixed

Comment: T N thank you for the link, it also provides a workaround. But bosniandev, can you post your workaround as well.